# Creating a callable with numexpr

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, numexpr

I'm doing some symbolic math with sympy, then generating a Python lambda function using `eval` and sympy's `lambdastr` utility. Here's a simplified example of what I mean:

```
import sympy
import numpy as np
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdastr

# simple example expression (my use-case is more complex)
expr = sympy.S('b*sqrt(a) - a**2')
a, b = sorted(expr.free_symbols, key=lambda s: s.name)

func = eval(lambdastr((a,b), expr), dict(sqrt=np.sqrt))

# call func on some numpy arrays
foo, bar = np.random.random((2, 4))
print func(foo, bar)
```

This works, but I don't like the use of `eval`, and sympy doesn't necessarily generate computationally-efficient code. Instead, I'd like to use `numexpr`, which seems perfect for this use-case:

```
import numexpr
print numexpr.evaluate(str(expr), local_dict=dict(a=foo, b=bar))
```

The only problem is that I'd like to generate a callable (like the `func` lambda), instead of calling `numexpr.evaluate` every time. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following with the ask here ... But can't you just wrap the `numexpr.evaluate` call in a `lambda` function?

Comment: I suppose I could, but would that incur the cost of re-parsing the expression string at every evaluation?

Comment: Can you [`lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html)?

Comment: Oh, wow, I completely missed `lambdify`. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: numexpr expressions are cached, so reuse is fast:  https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide#usage-notes

Comment: Will do, glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [`lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) module, which allows you to transform SymPy expressions to lambda functions for efficient calculation. This is nice in its ability to return a function with an attached implementation.

`Lambdify`ing your own function could look something like this:

```
func = lambdify((a,b),expr, dict(sqrt=np.sqrt))
```

Comment: Works great, though you don't need the parens around `expr`. Thanks!